# Barrett's esophagus (BO) and proton-pump inhibitors (PPIs)

Tags: medications, cancer, reference-request, esophagus

I have come across an interview with a European gastroenterologist (apparently from 2006) where he argues that in cases where a reflux disease does not cause typical symptoms even the presence of a Barrett's esophagus (BO) does not indicate prescription of proton-pump inhibitors (PPIs), because they have (the reduction of stomach acid production caused by them has) not yet been shown to be effective in preventing esophageal carcinoma.

I am wondering whether this is a mainstream or a minority view among specialists and what literature the interviewee may have been referring to. (E.g. [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4199831/) meta-analysis from 2014 apparently concludes with different recommendations.)

Comment: Excellent question!  Can you link to the interview?  The use of PPI is a hot topic under extensive debate during the recent years.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Unfortunately, I can't locate it online right now, but I'll give it another try.

Comment: When you speak of esophageal carcinoma, are you referring to adenocarcinoma or squamous-cell carcinoma? I ask because adenocarcinoma is associated with Barrett's esophagus more so than squamous-cell.

Answer (score 1):

Are PPIs effective in prevention of esophageal carcinoma in individuals with Barrett's esophagus? **The evidence is conflicting**; I listed it from yes to no.

[Acid-suppressive medications and risk of oesophageal adenocarcinoma in patients with Barrett's oesophagus: a systematic review and meta-analysis (Gut, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24221456):

> Based on meta-analysis of observational studies, the use of PPIs is
>   associated with a decreased risk of OAC and/or BO-HGD in patients with
>   BO. None of the studies showed an increased risk of OAC. PPI use
>   should be considered in BO, and chemopreventive trials of PPIs in
>   patients with BO are warranted.

[GERD and Peptic Ulcers (Indian Health Service, 2018)](https://www.ihs.gov/sites/nptc/themes/responsive2017/display_objects/documents/guidance/NPTC-Formulary-Brief-GERD-&-PUD.pdf):

> ...observational data suggest that PPIs are most effective for
>   preventing progression of Barrett’s to cancer

[Esomeprazole and aspirin in Barrett's oesophagus (AspECT): a randomised factorial trial (The Lancet, 2018)](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(18)31388-6/fulltext):

> Our data indicate that high-dose PPI (40 mg twice-daily) is better
>   than low-dose (20 mg once-daily) for patients with Barrett's
>   oesophagus in terms of delaying death, cancer, and dysplasia.

[Chemoprevention of Barrett’s oesophagus: a step closer with PPIs and aspirin (Clinical Oncology, 2018)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41571-018-0096-x):

> On the basis of the findings from AspECT and the evidence from
>   observational studies, we believe that PPI use in clinical practice
>   for chemoprevention in patients with Barrett’s oesophagus is
>   justified...The finding that aspirin was beneficial moves us one step
>   closer to broader recommendations for aspirin use in patient with
>   Barrett’s oesophagus and for prevention of chronic diseases in
>   general.

[Aspirin Plus PPI Prevents Esophageal Cancer (Medscape, 2018)](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/897636):

> Combined use of aspirin and a high-dose proton pump inhibitor (PPI)
>   protects against the development of esophageal cancer in people who
>   are at elevated risk for the malignancy, according to the results of a
>   major phase 3 chemoprevention trial from the United Kingdom, the
>   Aspirin and Esomeprazole Chemoprevention in Barrett's Metaplasia
>   (AspECT) trial.

[Will a Proton Pump Inhibitor and an Aspirin Keep the Doctor Away for Patients With Barrett’s Esophagus? (Gastroenterology, 2019)](https://www.gastrojournal.org/article/S0016-5085(19)32511-9/fulltext):

> Most patients with known Barrett’s esophagus have symptomatic
>   gastroesophageal reflux disease. The study would support using a PPI
>   for acid suppression for such patients. Some patients lack
>   gastroesophageal reflux disease by symptoms, endoscopic findings, or
>   even pH testing; for these patients, the benefit is uncertain or
>   unlikely.

[Proton Pump Inhibitors Do Not Reduce the Risk of Esophageal Adenocarcinoma in Patients with Barrett's Esophagus: A Systematic Review and Meta-Analysis (PLosOne, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28072858):

> No dysplasia- or cancer-protective effects of PPIs usage in patients
>   with BE were identified by our analysis.

[Maintenance proton pump inhibition therapy and risk of oesophageal cancer (Cancer Epidemiology, 2018)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877782118300687?via%3Dihub):

> In conclusion, the long term use of PPIs is associated with increased
>   risk of oesophageal adenocarcinoma in the absence of other risk
>   factors. Long term use of PPIs should be addressed with caution.

Comment: This is, of course, anecdotal and applies only to me: I have been taking pantoprazole 20mg twice daily for the past 2 ½ years. I have esophageal cancer (adenocarcinoma) and a PET/CT scan detected evidence of Barrett's esophagus.